# Flutter listview always expands to available width

Tags: flutter

What I need is green box should end where the text ends.
Here's my code

```
    Widget buildFlexible() {
    return Flexible(
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
        children: [
          MessageBubble(title: 'Test1'),
          MessageBubble(title: 'Test2'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: [
              buildFlexible(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MessageBubble({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Material(
        child: Text(title),
        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        // elevation: 5.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `Padding` widget from your `MessageBubble` class with the `Wrap()` widget

[image]

**So, the final code for the `MessageBubble` should be:**

```
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MessageBubble({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Material(
          child: Text(title),
          color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          // elevation: 5.0,
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same result with just using a `Container` widget and by removing the `Material` widget and the `Padding` widget as:

```
Wrap(children: [
     Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
         child: Text('hi'),
         color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
     )
])
```

Instead of:

```
Wrap(children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Material(
              child: Text(title),
              color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
              // elevation: 5.0,
            ),
          )
        ]);
```