# Message box doesnt expand according to the message length

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making a chat application where the message box should expand according to the message length. This works fine for only text but i am listing a series of small images also on the message box but on this case the message box doesn't expand.

This is the code:

```
Column(
                        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width:100,
                            height:40,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              //shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: checkregexpression(argument['message'])
                                  .length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return checkregexpression(
                                            argument['message'])[index] ==
                                        '†'
                                    ? Image.asset('assets/emojis/' +
                                        currentemoji[i++] +
                                        '.png')
                                    : Text(checkregexpression(
                                            argument['message'])[index]
                                        .toString());
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
```

I have used box constraint for this but listing a series of image displays the text and images on a horizontal scroll view rather than expanding accordingly. if possible an example of how to include box constraint onto a list view will also help.

[image]

Comment: You have given thr width of the container to be 100. How can it grow?

Comment: removing that it just increases the width but still on horizontal scroll view

Comment: You have used horizontal listview , what you’re expecting?

Comment: Please read what are the purpose of widgets and properties before using them

Comment: ok if possible can you give me an example of a list view inside a box constraint if that makes sense.

Comment: You can wrap your children widgets: text and the image using a column widget as you have done and thrn wrap that column widget using the ``Wrap`` widget if you want it to take space based on the text

Comment: ok thanks i will try

Comment: Check this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/68319665/5882307

Comment: will it work on list view also